# Regular expression to remove bullets from the text is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to remove Bullets from the text using javascript regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469153/how-to-remove-bullets-from-the-text-using-javascript-regular-expression)
>   [How to identify and Remove any type of Bullet in the Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479059/how-to-identify-and-remove-any-type-of-bullet-in-the-text)

I am copyig some data from the MS Word. That text may contain or May not contain Bullets in the copied text. But i need a Regular expression in javascript to remove any type of Bullets from the copied text.My code is given below.As of now it is removing  only •.

```
 var x = "1.   Jnflkvkbfjvb  2.   Kjnfbhvjbv  3.   ;kbvrjvbrjvb    •    Jnflkvkbfjvb    •    Kjnfbhvjbv    •    ;kbvrjvbrjvb     a)   Jnflkvkbfjvb  b)   Kjnfbhvjbv  c)   ;kbvrjvbrjvb    A.   Jnflkvkbfjvb  B.   Kjnfbhvjbv  C.   ;kbvrjvbrjvb     I.      Jnflkvkbfjvb  II.      Kjnfbhvjbv III.      ;kbvrjvbrjvb ";
 x = x.replace(/[•\t.+]/g, '');
 x = x.replace(/[[1-9]{?}+[.]\t]/g, '');
 alert(x);
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: What is the desired output and what is the actual output?

Comment: The regular expression you've got does not look correct to me, but it's not clear what it should be.

Comment: Suppose if you are created a Bullet list in word and copied it to a Text area in a web page. By the default bullets will come with text. I want to remove them.

Comment: I think you should have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Whats wrong with my answer to [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479059/how-to-identify-and-remove-any-type-of-bullet-in-the-text/6480127#6480127) that you accepted?

Comment: -1 for posting a duplicate of a well-answered question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = x.replace(/\d\.\s+|[a-z]\)\s+|•\s+|[A-Z]\.\s+|[IVX]+\.\s+/g, "");
```

It's basically a compound of various bullets you'd like to remove:

- `\d\.\s+` - numbered bullets
- `[a-z]\)\s+` - small letter bullets with closing brace
- `•\s+` - usual bullet
- `[A-Z]\.\s+` - upper case bullets with dots
- `[IVX]+\.\s+` - Roman numbered bullets

Comment: This is great! I have another issue where I have different sizes of bullets. For e.g. '•' and '●'. How do I clean such kind of bullets?

Comment: @satishsilveri replace the `•\s+` with the `[•●]\s+`. Put in the square brackets all the different single character bullets that are in your text.

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = "1.   Jnflkvkbfjvb  2.   Kjnfbhvjbv  3.   kbvrjvbrjvb\
•    Jnflkvkbfjvb  •    Kjnfbhvjbv  •    kbvrjvbrjvb\
a)   Jnflkvkbfjvb  b)   Kjnfbhvjbv  c)   kbvrjvbrjvb\
A.   Jnflkvkbfjvb  B.   Kjnfbhvjbv  C.   kbvrjvbrjvb\
I.   Jnflkvkbfjvb  II.  Kjnfbhvjbv  III. kbvrjvbrjvb";

x = x.replace(/([0-9A-Z]+[.)]|•)\s+/gi, "");

alert(x);
```

Removes all bullets from the sample text. Be careful, as this might also remove text you do not want to remove.

Explanation:

```
(              # group 1
  [0-9A-Z]+    #   any combination of digits 0-9 or letters A-Z
  [.)]         #   either a dot or a closing paren
  |            #   ...or
  •            #   a bullet sign
 )\s+          # end group 1, match any following whitespace
```

Comment: +1 nearly the same answer I gave him to this question the last time he asked it [how-to-identify-and-remove-any-type-of-bullet-in-the-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479059/how-to-identify-and-remove-any-type-of-bullet-in-the-text/6480127#6480127)

Comment: @stema: I see. Obviously explaining things sometimes is not enough to make them stick. :-\ Closed question as duplicate. Some people really make me wonder if they are doing this for fun.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to explain it two times ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is overzealous use of brackets.  Try this:

```
x= x.replace(/[•\t]+/g, '');
x= x.replace(/[1-9]{?}+[.]\t/g, '');
```

Brackets create a group of characters to match against.  When you wrapped up the whole thing in brackets it was trying to match just any single character within the group of characters within the brackets (and there's no nesting, so it was eating up all the duplicates in the second query).

Comment: What do you expect `[1-9]{?}+` to do? It will match something like `1{}}}` See [here](http://regexr.com?2u3hr). I am sure thats not what you intended.